# Install python module for one user without root access?

Tags: installation, python, user-accounts

I have a Python program that uses wxPython and I bundle with py2app on Mac. This worked perfectly fine under 2.6 (I had `wx` and `py2app` installed in 2.6). But because of some bugs in the `zipfile` library under 2.6 (like not being able to zip or unzip files), I have to use 2.7.3. My administrator installed Python 2.7.3, so `zipfile` is no longer a problem. But, 2.7.3 doesn't come with py2app, and since my highly qualified administrator is afraid of terminals, I can't install py2app. I thought of `virtualenv`, but wxPython refuses to install on a virtualenv.

So, bottom line, is there any way I can install py2app for just my user, so I don't need root/sudo? Whether it's just the library, or a completely new python installation, or any other method, I need 2.7.3 with py2app and wxpython.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can install modules for non-root users using

```
pip install --user py2app
```

I believe `easy_install -U py2app` also works...

Comment: I don't have `pip`, and `easy_install` doesn't have a `--user`. Can I download `pip` and run it without installing to /usr/bin or anything?

Comment: try `easy_install -U`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: --upgrade (-U): force upgrade (searches PyPI for latest versions)